# Prove that $\overline{\mathrm{span}\lbrace x_k\rbrace_{k=1}^\infty}=\ell^2$ where $x_k := (0, ..., \underset{\text{k-th spot}}{1/\sqrt k}, 0, 0,...,)$

Tags: orthonormal

Define
$$
x_k := (0, ..., \underset{\text{k-th spot}}{1/\sqrt k}, 0, 0,...,),
$$
for all $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$, then indeed
$$
\overline{\mathrm{span}\lbrace x_k \rbrace_{k=1}^\infty} = \ell^2.
$$
I would like to check this statement. Then I thought to do as follows. First, the set $x_k$ is clearly orthogonal. Then for each $x\in\ell^2$ we have
$$x=\sum_k \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k$$
and
$$\|x\|^2=\sum_k |\langle x,x_k\rangle|^2$$
Orthogonal decomposition of $\ell^2$: $\ell^2=X\oplus X^{\perp}$ where $X=\overline{\mathrm{span}\lbrace x_k \rbrace_{k=1}^\infty}$. If I consider $x\in X^{\perp}$ we have that $\langle x, x_k\rangle=0$ for each $k$. Thus $\|x\|^2=\sum_k |\langle x,x_k\rangle|^2=0$ and so $x=0$. But this means that $X^{\perp}=\{0\}$ and thus the claim. Right?

Comment: $X=\mathrm{span}\lbrace x_k \rbrace_{k=1}^\infty $

Comment: Then $X\oplus X^{\perp}\subsetneq \ell^2.$ I think you meant $X=\overline{\mathrm{span}\lbrace x_k \rbrace_{k=1}^\infty}.$ In any case, you should add it in your text.

Comment: So my proof is wrong :-( how would you do it?

Comment: Yes it is wrong but not there (just define your $X$ correctly). What is wrong is $x=\sum_k \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k.$ Why do you bother with those $\sqrt k$? Life would be easier with $\delta_k$ than $x_k$ (and $X$ would be the same).

Comment: It's much more direct. If $y=(y_i)\in\ell^2$ then define $z_k=\sum_{i=1}^k y_i\sqrt{i} x_i\in X$ and then $z_k\to y.$

Comment: Yes, i.e. $z_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle y,\delta_k\rangle\delta_k.$

Comment: I added $X=\overline{\mathrm{span}\lbrace x_k \rbrace_{k=1}^\infty}$ to my text. What is $\delta_k$?

Comment: Quick tip: when writing "span" it is better to use `\operatorname` than `\mathrm` as it maintains better spacing

Comment: I can't understand why $x=\sum_k \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k$ is wrong. For an orthonormal system $\left\{x_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, we have that $\left\{x_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis and that
$x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\langle x, x_k\right\rangle x_k, \quad \forall x \in \mathcal{H}$.